# Bias and Variance of a Honest Random Forest

Tags: variance, random-forest, causality, bias, computational-statistics

I am trying to read the paper [Estimation and Inference of Heterogeneous Treatment
Effects using Random Forests](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04342). In the section 3.1(Theoretical Background), page 13 paragraph 2, The authors have estimated the bias and variance of a honest random forest for a specific type of data and sub-sampling size. I don't know how.

Details:

In the paper [Mentch and Hooker [2016]](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume17/14-168/14-168.pdf) the authors have showed that the bias of Random forest using sub-sampling approaches Gaussian distribution if the sub-sampling size grows slower than $\sqrt{n}$.
In the [Estimation and Inference of Heterogeneous Treatment
Effects using Random Forests](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04342) the authors say that estimate will not be in general asymptotically unbiased using an example below:
Given ($X$<sub>i</sub>,$Y$<sub>i</sub>) $\in$ $[$$0$,$1$$]$$^d$$\times$$R$ and $d$$=$$2$, $\mu$($x$)$=$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$ and $\mu$($x$)$=$$\lVert x \rVert$<sub>1</sub>, for this if honest forest is evaluated at x=0 they say that the bias of the random forest decays as $1/$$\sqrt{s_n}$ and variance decays as $s$<sub>n</sub>$/$$n$.  I don't how they got this bias and variance decay rate.
Could someone please explain. Thanks in advance.